# How to remove password of a password-protected PRC?

Tags: encryption, password-protection, palm

I know the password, I just want to remove it. Mobidedrm couldn't do this (it can remove DRM from files that are not password-protected only though). any idea?

[Sample file on DropBox](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26880268/sample.prc)

passwd of sample file is `stent`

Comment: More information is required.

Comment: @Ramhound what kind of information should I add?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the DRM or just the password? AFAIK the .prc files are just .mobis with a different extension. http://apprenticealf.wordpress.com should be able to help if it's DRM.

Comment: just the password only but the file is password protected and DRM-protected as well.